# Not able to get access token from AAD using ADAL from xamarrin forms UWP app

Tags: authentication, xamarin, uwp, adal

I am trying to get access token from AAD from my Xamarin.Forms UWP app but not able to pass through authentication. Getting below login popup from my UWP app.[image: See Login popup here]

Implemented code by following this blog https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin-forms/

This issues is observed only on my virtual machine, where as I am able to retrieve token from my local win10 machine.

Fiddler trace shows the below, [image: this response]

Checked in my browser settings and JavaScript is already enabled.

Can someone please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: virtual machine? Could you share more derail about your virtual machine?

Comment: The control of the below login page is WebView, and you need to set **Edge** browser  enable `JavaScript`, for more detail you could refer this [solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/how-to-enable-javascript-in-microsoft-edge/ba12aa2e-6f2f-4d87-a990-5c1d2fd7036c?auth=1).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @NicoZhu-MSFT , I tried enabling scripts for from settings as mentioned in the above link but still no success.

Comment: I guess there are some network issues in  your visual machine.Have you tried to repair the network manually?

Comment: @NarenderReddy - can you please add more information? For example, you only show a screens shot with the authorize endpoint - it would be good to have a list of more requests - earlier and after the above. And also about how your app registration is configured (native or web)